# extensions don't install automatically in vs code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

vs code doesn't install any extension automatically, I have to install and import it manually, how to make it install the extensions automatically?

The extension page looks like that and here is the console in toggle developer tools:

[image: text]

Comment: And what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the extension automatically in VS code. For doing this you can do something like this

```
code --install-extension <extension-vsix-path>
code --install-extension <extension-id>
```

You can use following command to install extension. If you have the extension downloaded into local PC you can use the local path as well as extension id which will download it from gallery.